# With SqlServer, is there a performance penalty (or additional call) for using TransactionScope for a single statement?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, transactionscope

I have a process that updates SqlServer.  Sometimes that process is a single statement(UPDATE...) and sometimes it is several statements, each using `sp_executesql` .  Standardizing on wrapping the one or many statements in a TransactionScope would greatly simplify my code, and prevent me from having to flag each process as 'withintransaction' or not.

For reference, encapsulating a transaction would look something like this:

```
    using(var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{...one or more sql statements... transactionScope.Complete();}
```

I've run SqlProfiler on the entries.

*SqlProfiler entries without wrapping in a TransactionScope:*

```
exec sp_executesql <update statement>
exec sp_reset_connection
```

*SqlProfiler entries with wrapping in a TransactionScope:*

```
exec sp_executesql <update statement> TransactionID=12345
exec sp_reset_connection TransactionID=12345
```

Based on those entries my guess is that calling transaction.Complete() does not incur an additional call but rather completes the transaction in the exec_sp_reset_connection.

So I'm looking for definitive answers to the following:

- Does using TransactionScope() have any best practices for single sql statements?
- Does calling transactionScope.Complete() incur an additional db call?

Much appreciated!

Comment: I changed the first bullet to not specifically be about performance but about best practices.  Testing performance on a relational db, with transactions to boot, has so many different environments (local/staging/server...magnetic/ssd/inmemory...no concurrency/highread/highwrite) that I'm hoping there's guidance regarding best practices.  I believe EF wraps everything in a transaction regardless.  Does this mean we should do this when handrolling sql?

Comment: There was a stack question that tackles point 1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151986/is-it-good-practice-to-always-use-a-transactionscope-in-a-dal-base-class

Comment: but you might get a better response over on database administrators.

Comment: Thanks,
I did a quick performance check locally looping 1000 over the same update query with/without transactionscope per call.  Adding the transaction scope definitely slowed things down by perhaps 20-30%.  It was significant enough for me to work it into my repositories to sniff whether it's a single operation or multiple.